# Как выделить активную категорию в левом меню ocstore 2.3?

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

Допустим мы зашли в категорию apple

my_site.ru/apple

На странице в левом боковом меню выводятся категории и их подкатегории, дело в том, что мне нужно было сделать раскрывающийся список подкатегорий при клике на соответствующую категорию и я убрал на js ссылки из **a**

```
$(elem).find('a').removeAttr('href);
```

Теперь не знаю каким способом выделить активную категорию (в которой мы сейчас находимся). Есть варианты? Может как-то в контроллере и в шаблоне можно схитрить?

Comment: Если у активной категории есть отличающийся класс, типа `active` то можно через css ее выделить, если класса нет то сравнивайте через `href ` ссылки категории с ссылкой в адресной строкой, но лучше так не делать это уже совсем крайние меры. Как вариант это нужно делать на этапе вывода, как то делал такое с год назад, там в каком файле нужно пару строчек дописать чтобы выводить класс для активной категории.

Comment: Дело в том что никакого отличающегося класса нет и я написал выше что ***href*** удалял с помощью _js_ в некоторых элементах ***a***